# How to share QGIS R Processing Toolbox

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, rqgis

I have developed a R Processing Toolbox. This has the file name: ToolboxRQGIS.rsx

How can I share this toolbox with my colleagues in the easiest way?

For a QGIS plugin, I can archive the developed plugin into a zip folder. Then, I can store the .zip file centrally on a server and my colleagues can install the plugin via: Extensions > Install extension from .zip file

Is there a similar easy way I can share a R Processing Toolbox?